# Being reassigned from remote work back to the office to cover for someone who has concerns re corona virus

Tags: united-states, discrimination, safety, government

The entire office is being assigned to remote work at home which is what I did.

But now I have to do a different job at the office. Only two of us have to.

Is it legal for my federal employer to reassign me from working at home to a different job at the office where I have constant contact with the public because a coworker has concerns about getting the corona virus?

Comment: Please state a country, otherwise this question is not answerable.

Comment: The use of the word “federal” is a massive clue without reading to the end where that country info has been added... @nvoigt

Comment: @SolarMike clues are relative, I had no idea what federal was but now assume it's something to do with the USA. It's like a question including a Kohanga Reo, would you immediately know it's New Zealand?

Comment: @Kilisi well could be Switzerland but I doubt it ... and so many films etc talk federal government...

Comment: @SolarMike mabe, I don't know... I just fast forward to the action bits.

Comment: @SolarMike You really think the United States is the only federation of states on the planet? Have a look: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federation

Comment: @nvoigt if you read my last comment you will have the answer... or did you miss that?

Comment: @SolarMike I can read and see. I just wanted to inform you that your "clue" theory does not hold, because "federal" could also apply to such "small" countries like Russia, Brazil or India. So we should not answer based on clues. The country information has been added after my comment and I'm happy with that.

Comment: So what does you contract say? Not in the US, but here in Germany contracts usually state that the Employer can assign you where it fits them, as long as it does not place an undue burden on you (you´d have to relocate etc.) If you worked in that office before I´d say that is ok now unless you want to make the case that that is an undue burden.

Answer (score 1):

It is NOT illegal for your federal employer to reassign you from working at home to a different job at the office, that's it.

Now, you have concerns like everyone else so you can tell your employer your concerns so maybe you can become the coworker with concerns about getting the corona virus.

If you qualify to one of these conditions you might legally get back to home safety: https://legalaidatwork.org/factsheet/coronavirus-faq/